# Bootstrap alert display on next page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

[image]Here is my code

```
else {
        var tag = document.getElementById('scripttag');
        $(tag).css('display', 'none');
                    document.write("<div class='alert alert-info alert-dismissable'>");
                    document.write("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;");
                    document.write("</button>");
                    document.write("No audios to display");
                    document.write("</div>");  
    }
```

when else condition occur then alert display on next new page and with simple button of close..it shows like above picture 
I want to display alert on my home page with color effect
any suggestion plz

Comment: Whats the exact problem? What do you expect to happen? I see no question in this.

Comment: @Sourabh- plz check my updated quesiton

Comment: So you want to navigate only when you hit the close button of the alert right?

Comment: why it is showing like this..without any effect of bootstrap color? is it problem in my code? and also why it is navigate to different page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `document.write()` , place your code in HTML including `display:none` :

```
<div style="display:none" class='alert alert-info alert-dismissable'>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    No audios to display
</div>
```

Then in **JS**, in your `else` use

```
$(".alert").show();
```

to show the alert.

Comment: i have to set it on onclick of li but click on close button it doesnot show again

Comment: What do you mean it doesnot show again? To show again use $(".alert").show(), whenever you want to show it again